# how to push multiple values in array

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to push multiple values in a array so as to send to php but it is inserting only first value. How can i push multiple values in array using jquery so that i can send that array to ajax and process it in php?

Here is my HTML markup:

```
<form role="form" name="form_name" id="inventory_form" method="post" action="javascript:;">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="inv_tbl">
            <thead>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>~</th>
                <th>Barcode</th>
                <th>Product Name</th>
                <th>SM</th>
                <th>SPL</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Discount</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th><input type="button" value="+" id="add" class="btn btn-primary add_inv_row"></th>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="detail">
                <tr>
                    <td class="no">1</td>
                    <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox" id="till_check" class="is_checked" name="till_check[]" value="Bike"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="barcode[]" id="barcode" class="form-control selectpicker barcode" data-live-search="true">
                            <option value="">Please select a barcode</option>
                            <?php  foreach($barcodes as $barcode) :?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $barcode->barcode; ?>"><?php echo $barcode->barcode; ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="brcode_product" class="form-control productname" name="productname[]"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="sm[]" id="sm" class="form-control selectpicker sm" data-live-search="true">
                            <option value="">Please select a Employee code</option>
                            <?php  foreach($employee_codes as $employee_code) :?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $employee_code->emp_code; ?>"><?php echo $employee_code->emp_code; ?></option>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="spl" class="form-control spl" name="spl[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="quantity" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="price" class="form-control price" name="price[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="discount" class="form-control discount" name="discount[]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="amount" class="form-control amount" name="amount[]"></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="remove">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-success" id="save_btn" type="submit" name="sale_submit_btn">Save</button></th>
                <th style="text-align:center;" class="total">0<b></b></th>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
   </div> 
   <?php// echo form_close(); ?>
</form>
```

Here is my code :

```
  function addnewrow() {
    var n = ($('.detail tr').length - 0) + 1;

    var tr = '<tr>' +
        '<td class="no">' + n + '</td>' +
        '<td><input type="checkbox" class="till_check" name="till_check[' + till_check_counter + ']" id="till_check[' + till_check_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><select class="form-control barcode selectpicker  dyselect_' + product_barcode_counter + '" data-live-search="true" name="barcode[' + product_barcode_counter + ']" id="barcode[' + product_barcode_counter + ']">' + '<option>Please select a bar code</option>' + '</select></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control prdctn_' + product_name_counter + ' productname"  id="brcode_product['+product_name_counter+']"  name="productname[' + product_name_counter + ']" id="productname[' + product_name_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><select class="form-control selectpicker dysm_' + sm_counter + ' sm " data-live-search="true" name="sm[' + sm_counter + ']" id="sm[' + sm_counter + ']">' + '<option>Please select a Employee code</option>' + '</select></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control spl" name="spl[' + spl_counter + ']" id="spl[' + spl_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="quantity[' + product_quantity_counter + ']" id="quantity[' + product_quantity_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="price[' + product_price_counter + ']" id="price[' + product_price_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control discount" name="discount[' + product_discount_counter + ']" id="discount[' + product_discount_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><input type="text" class="form-control amount" name="amount[' + product_amount_counter + ']" id="amount[' + product_amount_counter + ']"></td>' +
        '<td><a href="#" class="remove">Delete</td>' +
        '</tr>';
    $('.detail').append(tr);
    
    // incrementing the counter
    ++product_barcode_counter;
    ++till_check_counter;
    ++product_name_counter;
    ++product_quantity_counter;
    ++sm_counter;
    ++spl_counter;
    ++product_price_counter;
    ++product_discount_counter;
    ++product_amount_counter;
    
    
    

    //setting the validation rules for every product attribute by calling the function 
    createValidation();
    get_barcodes();
    get_employee_codes();
  
    //Send ajax request to the function on pressing the save button
   

   


} 

$('#save_btn').on('click', function () {

           
            var barcode = [];
            var productname = [];
            var sm = [];
            var spl = [];
            var quantity = [];
            var price = [];
            var discount = [];
            var amount = [];
            
            $('.barcode  option:selected').each(function(){
                barcode.push = $('#barcode  option:selected').val();
                
                
            });
            $('.productname').each(function(){
                productname.push = $(this).val();
                
                
            });
            $('.sm  option:selected').each(function(){
                sm.push = $(this).val();
               
                
            });
            $('.spl').each(function(){
                spl.push = $(this).val();
                
            });
            $('.quantity').each(function(){
                quantity.push = $(this).val();
               
            });
            $('.price').each(function(){
                price.push = $(this).val();
                
            });
            $('.discount').each(function(){
                discount.push = $(this).val();
               
            });
            $('.amount').each(function(){
                amount.push = $(this).val();
               
            });
        
            console.log(barcode);
            console.log(productname);
            console.log(sm);
            console.log(spl);
            console.log(quantity);
            console.log(price);
            console.log(discount);
            console.log(amount);
        
            /*$.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/retail/main/store",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    barcode: barcode,
                    productname: productname,
                    sm: sm,
                    spl: spl,
                    quantity: quantity,
                    price: price,
                    discount: discount,
                    amount: amount
                    
                },
                success: function (data) {
                   alert(data);
                }

            });*/
            
            /*var barcode = $('#barcode  option:selected').val();
            var productname = $('#brcode_product').val();
            var sm = $('#sm  option:selected').val();
            var spl = $('#spl').val();
            var quantity = $('#quantity').val();
            var price = $('#price').val();
            var discount = $('#discount').val();
            var amount = $('#amount').val();*/
         
            
            
      
        


     /*  var dataString = 'barcode=' + barcode + '&productname=' + productname + '&sm=' + sm + '&spl=' + spl + '&quantity' + quantity + '&price=' + price + '&discount=' + discount + '&amount=' + amount;*/
     
          
          
          
  
        
        
           
          

    });
```

Please do not consider the commented code.

Comment: `push` is a function, `barcode.push($('#barcode  option:selected').val());`

Comment: why do you have `$('.barcode')` and `$('#barcode')`

Comment: I was checking the code from where i can get the value of the field that is why i try to put both for testing purpose... but what i found that each time the same value is pushed in array.

Comment: @PranaySute - Why are you Submitting Form using javascript , is their any  reason ?

Comment: @AmitChauhan Yes there is a reason because i am using bootstrap selecpicker and the selectpicker doesn't allow a form to be submitted using  php so you will have to submit the form using ajax if you use bootstrap selectpicker in your form.

Comment: @PranaySute then use 
var frmData = $("#frm_name").serialize();

then use serialize method .